# How can I store a blob in a form and send it to the server when the clicks on submit without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my function:

```
FileCropped.prototype.change = function () {
    var obj = $(this).data("plugin.file-cropped");

    var files = obj.$element[0].files;
    var file;

    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobURL;

    if (files && files.length) {
        file = files[0];
        console.log("I have files");

        if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
            blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            obj.$element.val('');
            obj.$hidden[0].value = blobURL;
            //URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
        } else {
            window.alert('Please choose an image file.');
        }
    } else
    {
        console.log("No files?");
    }
}
```

I am trying right now to attach the blob to an existing form input but it does not work. With the chrome debugger I see the method works fine and follow the expected path, but at the time of submit the server gets nothing.

Any hint?

Edit: of course the function has no value right now. I could just use the normal file input. The goal is to be able to manipulate the blob before attaching it to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileReader to read the file as data URL

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.addEventListener('load', function () {
    blobURL = fileReader.result;
    obj.$hidden[0].value = blobURL;
});
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```